# Ruby regxep

Tags: регулярные-выражения, ruby

Подскажите как у Ruby, будет аналогичное

```
sed -i 's;bla;;g' file
```

Answer (score 2):

```
"".gsub /regexp/
```

Если именно для файла, то `File.open(path,"r").readlines.join("\n").gsub(/regexp/)`

Можно еще так сделать: http://pastebin.com/rSLhkQpS

Answer (score 0):

А можно и так:

```
File.open(path).read.gsub!(/bla/, '')
```

Если знак \n в конце не нужен, можно отсечь:

```
File.open(path).read.gsub!(/bla/, '').chomp
```